# Is it possible to improve GPS accuracy using the GSM network?

Tags: gps, arm, microcontroller, gsm

I want to increase the GPS accuracy by taking the data from GSM modem, basically implement something like an assisted GPS(A-GPS) with a GPS. The board that I use, Mediatek Linkit One,has both GPS and GSM in it. Is it possible to implement this in the software code.

Answer (score 0):

The location you can obtain from the GSM network is that of the mast being used, not of the modem. Because of this, the geographic resolution is lower than that available using GPS. In addition, to resolve location from the GSM information, you require a database of mast locations for look-up.

To answer your question, using the method above, I don't think so. If you're talking about doing some clever stuff with GSM timing information though, then I'd be more inclined to think you could achieve something.